Git file patch with lib/s and web.xml changes
I'm trying to mantain a repository made with branches of the same core project but each branch has few elements (like for example css values and logo) who need to remain different, i was trying to do the changes on the main branch before creating a file patch to apply to all the other branches but i found few problems:

if i modify the web.xml the patch apply fail every time because the space error even if there are no spaces.
if i try to add lib/s or new files the info about the new file is wrote inside the file patch but the file is not added when i apply the patch and strangly if i continue to delete the file patch and i create another one the size of the file patch contines to grow.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way but is the only "working" way i found untill now.
I tryed to use the additional commands meanwhile i create the file patch but the web.xml problem and the new file problem remain
